# Approach for watching same Youtube video in same room using Websockets(socket.io)?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I am making an app in which there are atmost 5 users in the room and will be watching same video which is controlled by the user who created the room.
For e.g,
User1 comes to the site and create a room, now url will be generated to join the room like example.com/?room=xyz
Now, user2 joins the room from the url. Similarly, other users will join.
Now, user1 will have a button "Load video"(not visible to other users) which will load the youtube video and embed the video in a div of every user in this room.

How do I achieve this? Please help

Comment: Take a look at this this demo https://demo.crossbar.io/videocontrol/ for coordinating different browser tabs. The video here is remote controlled (which, I guess, would be a nice additional feature for your implementation), instead of remote-chose, but adapting this should be easy. For an explanation of the demo, see http://tavendo.com/blog/post/small-demo-of-a-pragmatic-use-of-wamp-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/) on how to create a custom youtube video player, you can combine it with [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to establish witch controls will appear. Using:

```
elements.control.removeClass('play replay').addClass('pause'); // In the example youTubeEmbed-jquery-1.0.js – Part 3
```

Using the "socket.emit" and "socket.on" and transmitting the type of privileges the user has, so the player adapts to the privileges of the current user (basically adding or removing CSS classes or changing the player properties).